How to remove all DataSync tables and objects after deleting the data sync in my Azure SQL Server database?
I created a sync between 2 databases in Azure, then I removed(deleted) the sync in Azure, but I still see a few tables that are from the sync(image below). Additionally there might be some other objects in the DB that I don't directly see in SSMS.
Question - What's the best way to get rid of anything related to the old DataSync I had created?
The only thing I found was this link but I'm not that strong with SQL administration and don't feel comfortable just copying and pasting in the commands and executing them.

Here is the SQL code found online. Should I run this?
declare @TableName nvarchar(max)
set @TableName = 'yourTableName'
--In case you wish to delete objects related to all the tables you can uncomment the following:
--set @TableName = ''

-- Generate the script to drop Data Sync tables
select 'drop table [DataSync].['+ st.name+ '];' from sys.tables as st join sys.schemas as ss on ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
where ss.name = 'DataSync' and st.name like '%' + @TableName + '_dss_%'

-- Generate the script to drop Data Sync stored procedures
select 'drop procedure [DataSync].['+ sp.name+ '];' from sys.procedures as sp join sys.schemas as ss on ss.schema_id = sp.schema_id
where ss.name = 'DataSync' and sp.name like '%' + @TableName + '_dss_%'

-- Generate the script to delete Data Sync triggers
select 'drop trigger [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
from sys.objects where type = 'TR' and name like '%' + @TableName + '_dss_%'

-- Generate the script to delete Data Sync-related udtt
select 'drop type  [DataSync].['+ st.name+ '];' from sys.types as st join sys.schemas as ss on st.schema_id = ss.schema_id
where ss.name = 'DataSync' and st.name like '%' + @TableName + '_dss_%'


FYI, syntax like '['+ st.name+ ']' is not injection safe; it can easily be escaped just like a single quote ('). If you want to inject object names you need to ensure you quote them properly, using QUOTENAME.

That's why I posted the link to the git that has them. So what do I do to remove the sync tables?? FYI - this is just my dev database, so I guess I could drop the database and create a new one! I have the migration scripts.

As for the statements you have they won't actually do anything; they'll just create some datasets with some DDL statements in a column. You'll be able to see what those statements are before you run them, as you'd need to copy and paste the statements from the results into a query window.

The scripts you have appear to be for deleting data related to specific tables you synced. The tables you have left look more like sync meta data i.e. not specific to one of your tables, unless those are your table names e.g. scheme_info? If they are meta data, and you care about removing them, it looks like you will just have to script the drop table(s) yourself (which should be mostly trivial).

I never created these tables (ex. DataSync.xxx) so I assume they are from the data async, but I can't really remember if they were there before I synced. I assume they're from the sync but not sure.

Their scheme is DataSync so that would be a fair guess

check if this similar SO thread answer helps you.

I saw that post, but I'm a little hesitant to just copy and paste and execute when deleting tables.
